# Use AWS X-Ray with Oracle SQL

Tags: aws-xray

I'm learning AWS X-Ray and I read about tracing MySQL and PostgreSQL queries with X-Ray SDK for Java [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-sqlclients.html). But I don't see a solution for X-Ray tracing with Oracle SQL. Is it possible to trace Oracle SQL with X-Ray?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be some support for Oracle via the new (undocumented) SQL Tracing decorator:

- [Oracle JDBC Interceptor for X-Ray](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java/issues/13)
- [Spring Boot 2 Support for Database Tracing](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java/issues/88#issuecomment-570328275)

Comment: I think I came across the information at https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java/issues/88#issuecomment-570328275, but there's no official documentation about how to use that or where to put those pieces of codes.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and found some solutions to this. At a minimum, to make X-Ray work with Oracle database, we need this dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-sql</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and also this configuration:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    dataSourceBuilder.url("insert_your_db_url");
    dataSourceBuilder.username("insert_your_username");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("insert_your_password");
    return TracingDataSource.decorate(dataSourceBuilder.build());
}
```

Lastly, need to add this before making a database call (usually by using a DAO object or JPA repository), so X-Ray can track the SQL used to call the database (customize your own try and catch):

```
try {
    SqlSubsegments.forQuery(dataSource.getConnection(), query.getQueryString());
} catch (SQLException exp) {
    System.out.println("sql exception");
}
```

For the dataSource variable to be found, you need to add:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

SqlSubsegments.forQuery(dataSource.getConnection(), query.getQueryString()) in the above try-catch block begins a subsegment. The second argument of the method, query.getQueryString(), will show up as sanitized query on the X-Ray Trace console. After the database call, you need to end it by adding:

```
AWSXRay.endSubsegment();
```